# How do I add a dimension to an array? (opposite of `squeeze`)

Tags: julia

I can never remember how to do this this.

How can go

- from a Vector (size `(n1)`) to a Column Matrix (size `(n1,1)`)?
- or from a Matrix (size `(n1,n2)`) to a Array{T,3} (size `(n1,n2,1)`)?
- or from a Array{T,3} (size `(n1,n2,n3)`) to a Array{T,4} (size `(n1,n2,n3, 1)`)?
- and so forth.

I want to know to take Array and use it to define a new Array with an extra singleton trailing dimension.
I.e. the opposite of `squeeze`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time before the Julia 1.0 release a `reshape(x, Val{N})` overload was added which for `N > ndim(x)` results in the adding of right most singleton dimensions.

So the following works:

```
julia> add_dim(x::Array{T, N}) where {T,N} = reshape(x, Val(N+1))
add_dim (generic function with 1 method)

julia> add_dim([3;4])
2×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 3
 4

julia> add_dim([3 30;4 40])
2×2×1 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 3  30
 4  40

julia> add_dim(rand(4,3,2))
4×3×2×1 Array{Float64,4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.0737563  0.224937  0.6996
 0.523615   0.181508  0.903252
 0.224004   0.583018  0.400629
 0.882174   0.30746   0.176758

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 0.694545  0.164272   0.537413
 0.221654  0.202876   0.219014
 0.418148  0.0637024  0.951688
 0.254818  0.624516   0.935076
```

Comment: Is `reshape(x, Val{N})` documented? I can't find it.

Comment: May have worked in the past, but is not working anymore (as of Julia v1.8)

Answer (score 21):

You can do this with `reshape`.

You could define a method for this:

```
add_dim(x::Array) = reshape(x, (size(x)...,1))
```

---

```
julia> add_dim([3;4])
2×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 3
 4

julia> add_dim([3;4])
2×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 3
 4

julia> add_dim([3 30;4 40])
2×2×1 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 3  30
 4  40

julia> add_dim(rand(4,3,2))
4×3×2×1 Array{Float64,4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.483307  0.826342   0.570934
 0.134225  0.596728   0.332433
 0.597895  0.298937   0.897801
 0.926638  0.0872589  0.454238

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 0.531954  0.239571  0.381628
 0.589884  0.666565  0.676586
 0.842381  0.474274  0.366049
 0.409838  0.567561  0.509187
```

Comment: `widen` is a confusing name for this operation because it already means something very different. Some people might read that code expecting it to be applied to each element of the array, as in `widen.(A)`.

Comment: @tholy, ok. changed to `add_dim`. though not 100% happy with that either. Do you have a suggestion for the name? I know TensorFlow uses `expand_dims(x, insert_at_ind)` but that has a second argument; rather than just using trailing.

Comment: another name possibility: `rpad(M,3)` will make Array M into a 3-dim Array by adding length 1 dimensions on the right (`lpad` similarly on the left). it overloads methods for strings, but sort of similar action. Definition could be something like: `Base.rpad(m::AbstractArray,n::Integer) = reshape(m,size(m)...,[1 for i=1:n-ndims(m)]...)`

Answer (score 4):

Another easy way other than reshaping to an exact shape, is to use `cat` and `ndims` together. This has the added benefit that you can specify "how many extra (singleton) dimensions you would like to add". e.g.

```julia
a = [1 2 3; 2 3 4];
cat(ndims(a) + 0, a)  # add zero singleton dimensions (i.e. stays the same)
cat(ndims(a) + 1, a)  # add one singleton dimension
cat(ndims(a) + 2, a)  # add two singleton dimensions
```

etc.

---

**UPDATE (julia 1.3)**. The syntax for `cat` has changed in julia 1.3 from `cat(dims, A...)` to `cat(A...; dims=dims)`.

Therefore the above example would become:

```julia
a = [1 2 3; 2 3 4];
cat(a; dims = ndims(a) + 0 )
cat(a; dims = ndims(a) + 1 )
cat(a; dims = ndims(a) + 2 )
```

etc.

Obviously, like Dan points out below, this has the advantage that it's nice and clean, but it comes at the cost of allocation, so if speed is your top priority and you know what you're doing, then in-place reshape operations will be faster and are to be preferred.

Comment: This solution looks clean, but note `reshape` methods are 40x times faster on a trivial benchmark with almost no allocation.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense; reshape just returns a "view" into the initial object (albeit not visibly so in terms of its returned type). I agree that if a view rather than a new array is the intended behaviour then a reshape-based approach would be preferable.

Comment: @chunjiw the syntax of the `cat` command has changed (not altogether surprising, julia kept changing syntax like underwear back then). I'll update with the new syntax.

Comment: Is there a way to insert a (singleton) dimension on the left instead of on the right?

Comment: @becko I don't think it's possible with this method. I would use `reshape` for that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
function extend_dims(A,which_dim)
       s = [size(A)...]
       insert!(s,which_dim,1)
       return reshape(A, s...)
       end
```

the variable `extend_dim` specifies which dimension to extend

Thus

```
extend_dims(randn(3,3),1)
```

will produce a `1 x 3 x 3` array and so on.

I find this utility helpful when passing data into convolutional neural networks.

Comment: I found this to be much more useful than the accepted answer.  Thank you!