# Convert Array{Int, 1} into Array{Int, 2}

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, julia

I use a function which take an Array{Int, 2} as an argument but it does not work when the array only contains 1 integer (as the array type is Array{Int, 1} in that case).

I know how to create an Array{Int, 2} with 2 or more integers:

```
S2 = [1 2] # S2 is an Array{Int, 2}
S3 = [1 2 3] # S3 is an Array{Int, 2}
```

but I don't know how to create an Array{Int, 2} with only 1 integer:

```
S1 = [1] # S1 is an Array{Int, 1}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a dimension to an array? (opposite of \`squeeze\`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312319/how-do-i-add-a-dimension-to-an-array-opposite-of-squeeze)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hcat` function, e.g.:

```
julia> hcat(1)
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
```

This also works if you want to convert vector to a matrix:

```
julia> x = [1]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> hcat(x)
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
```

EDIT: as an afterthought you can also do it like this:

```
julia> fill(10,1,1)
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 10
```

it is more complex, but this way you can simply create an object of higher dimension e.g.:

```
julia> fill(10,1,1,1)
1×1×1 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 10
```

EDIT 2: a general solution to put a new dimension of length `1` to any array in any place would be to use a comprehension:

```
julia> x = [1 2
            3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> [x[i,k] for i in 1:size(x,1), j in 1:1, k in 1:size(x,2)]
2×1×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1
 3

[:, :, 2] =
 2
 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `reshape`

```
julia> S1 = [1]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> reshape(S1,1,1)
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
```